# Mac: Show a PDF in a floating borderless window

Tags: osx, pdf-viewer

Video players like [IINA](https://iina.io/) let you view video in a floating, borderless window.

Is there any equivalent for PDF files?

I'm using PDF slides and am basically trying to get the equivalent functionality of viewing a PDF in full-screen (no window decorum, left/right arrows to move through slides), but *outside* of full-screen.

Alternatively, any software that can display PDF in some approaching way would be very welcome. Perhaps something like what [Simple Comic](http://dancingtortoise.com/simplecomic/) does (automatic window resizing to the content)?